# como forçar um buffer a se comportar como uma string em C?

Tags: c, string, buffer

Estou recebendo um buffer da internet, acredito que para percorrer esse buffer e encontrar o último caractere, é preciso encontrar o caractere '\0'. Mas não existe '\0' em um buffer.

É possível forçar esse buffer a se comportar como uma string?

Answer (score 2):

Acrescenta p `'\0'` ao buffer. Mas atencao a dados binarios!!

```
length = recv(socket, buffer, sizeof buffer - 1, 0);
buffer[length] = 0; // adiciona terminador
```